# How do I get the name of the branch that has had the most recent commit in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, batch-file, repository, hgrc

What I would like to do is query the HG repo to find the branch name of the last commit.

When a user pushes their commit to the repo, I am triggering a batch file via a hook in the *.hg/hgrc* file in the central repo.

Using *hg branch* in my local repo works fine, however the batch file I'm running resides on the central repo, meaning that it always returns 'default'

What i would like to do is go, 'Get the last committed revision and extract the branch name from that' regardless of what branch the central repo is on.

I hope this is possible, but may be it's not - any suggestions greatly appreciated

Here is a snippet from my batch file:

```
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
'hg branch'
) do (
set hg_branch=%%a
)
set dest=\\myrepo-%hg_branch%\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tip` is always the most recent changeset, so this will print the branch name:

```
hg log -r tip --template {branch}
```